# Horizontal scroll-bar going beyond container width

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm working on a landing page.

In the third section, I will have content with a horizontal scroll bar. I already have the desired scrolling behavior, but I'd like the scroll bar to respect the container of the page.

Here's my current code:

```css
.page {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .container {
        width: 60%;
        margin: auto;
      }

      h3 {
        background: #dbd0bc;
        color: #000;
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .hs {
        list-style: none;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 20% 2rem 20%;
      }

      .hs .item {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 17rem;
        background: #dbd0bc;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 0.75rem;
        height: 10rem;
        white-space: normal;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 15px;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
        background-color: gray;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 2rem;
      }
```

```html
<div class="page">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
      </div>

      <ul class="hs">
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
        <li class="item">section 3</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="container">
        <h3>Section 4</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here are two examples of what I'd like this to be like:
https://prnt.sc/n0o0k7
https://prnt.sc/n0o21r

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand the question. The third section wouldn't be styled correctly in the container because you didn't wrap it in the container. I moved the container class's styles to the page class's style and removed all the containers to achieve your desired effect.

```css
.page {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

h3 {
  background: #dbd0bc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hs {
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20% 2rem 20%;
}

.hs .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17rem;
  background: #dbd0bc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
  height: 10rem;
  white-space: normal;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 15px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: gray;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <ul class="hs">
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
    <li class="item">section 3</li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Section 4</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I need content rolling from the left corner to the right corner, 100% of the page width, this I already have in my code, I just need the scroll bar to be the size of the ".container"

Comment: Not sure you can accomplish this with a regular scrollbar. Not sure you'd want to either, since styling scrollbars is problematic cross-browser. Might not look very nice in Edge, for example. Maybe look into making a custom scrollbar over which you will have more control. The example you link to looks like it's using something custom.